# How to add a category ID to High Charts Category

Tags: highcharts

**Desired output:** I will have a dynamically generated highchart and I need to be able to put an ID in with the categories so that when they click on a category, I can pass it to a modal to do a drilldown.

I see questions on adding data to the series, but not categories.

**Current Code:** (This is not dynamically generated yet, still testing)

```
 $('#ChartContainer2').highcharts({

            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 20,
                    beta: 20,
                    viewDistance: 0,
                    depth: 70
                },
                marginTop: 90,
                marginBottom: 80
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Category Reset Pacing'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    depth: 25
                },
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function ()
                            {
                                $("#PacingModal").modal('show');                            
                                var Status = this.series.name;
                                var Cat = this.category; 
                                //get category id, something like
                                var ID = this.category.id;     
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    animation: {
                        duration: 3000,
                        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
                    },
                }
            },
            tooltip: {

                useHTML: true,
                shared: true,
                headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}:</td>' +
                    '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y}%</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',

            },
            xAxis: {
                //i need to add an ID to each category
                categories: ['15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                    '15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                    '15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                    '15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                    '15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                    '15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                    '15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',
                    '15-05 SFYBAKE Brooklyn Bred - Bakery Rack Display (NOR) Brooklyn Bred Rack in Bakery',

                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Percent Complete'
                }
            },

            series: [  {
                name: 'Not Complete',
                data: [30, 3, 5, 0, 5, 8, 0, 13],

            },{
                name: 'Clean Up',
                data: [10, 14, 11, 10, 15, 8, 0, 3],

            },
            {
                name: 'Complete',
                data: [60, 65, 78, 70, 45, 58, 80, 35],

            } ]
        });
```

**Updated:** After using the below answer, I found that it only, makes the label clickable. I need the entire bar to be clickable. Below is my updated code with what I am trying to make the entire bar clickable.

I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined".

made these changes to the above code.

```
    var categoryLinks = [
   ['Foo', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=foo'],
   ['Bar', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=foo+bar'],
   ['Foobar', 'http://www.google.com/serach?q=foobar'],
     ['Foo', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=foo'],
   ['Bar', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=foo+bar'],
   ['Foobar', 'http://www.google.com/serach?q=foobar']
    ];

Some code...

        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                depth: 25
            },
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function ()
                        {


     //Here is where I am trying to redirect on the bar click, not just the label          

     window.location.replace(this.categoryLinks[this.value][1]);


      //Also tried 
      window.location.replace(this.category.categoryLinks[this.value][1]); 


More code...

});
```

Comment: If you always know the order in which the categories are added you can use its index value. Or you can use the actual category string as your ID. But, looking at your categories they are all the same. Is that supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks man. We have millions of these categories, It will be completely dynamic. the string will not work. Do you know if what I am trying to do is possible with highcharts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explicit example from the API for this in [`xAxis.label.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter):
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-formatter-linked/

Essentially what they are doing is creating a list of category objects:

```
var categoryLinks = {
    'Foo': 'http://www.google.com/search?q=foo',
    'Bar': 'http://www.google.com/search?q=foo+bar',
    'Foobar': 'http://www.google.com/serach?q=foobar'
};
```

And then using the label.formatter to only show the human-readable text with a link using the value:

```
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<a href="' + categoryLinks[this.value] + '">' +
                this.value + '</a>';
        }
    }
```

For your revised question requiring being able to click on the bar to go to a URL please look at the API [`plotOptions.series.point.events.click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click). There is an explicit example there of going to a URL on point click.

Comment: And modified version to use external categories (array of arrays): http://jsfiddle.net/wr8mdd3d/ - where format is: `[name, extra_info]`.

Comment: @Hanoncs, file bug on github for the 3d item. Sounds like they may an error in upgrading.

Comment: Ok, So i got it working with your example on my bar chart. But the issue is that it only works on the labels, I need the entire bar to be click able. Please see my question I updated it.

Comment: This was not really the answer, but it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to keep id with category in Highchart. You can get each category id in click event.
[Please see the working code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eq57ps7q/2/)

```
objData={}
objData[0]= {
"category": ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August"],
"score":[48,25,0,80,71,100,100,44],
"id":["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08"],
"year":"2016",
"Y":"2016",
"minimum":[60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60]
};

$(function () {
            $('#chart').highcharts({credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {text: 'Company Performance', x: -20},
                subtitle: {text: 'For the year of' + objData[0].year, x: -20},
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    data = {
                                    month: objData[0].id[this.x],
                                    year: objData[0].Y
                                    };
                                   alert( objData[0].id[this.x]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {categories: objData[0].category},
                yAxis: {title: {text: 'Percentage'}, plotLines: [{value: 0, width: 1, color: '#808080'}]},
                tooltip: {valueSuffix: '%'},
                legend: {layout: 'vertical', align: 'right', verticalAlign: 'middle', borderWidth: 0},
                series: [{name: 'Min Score', color: '#A30000', data: objData[0].minimum}, {name: 'Score', color: '#10AEDE', data: objData[0].score}],
            });
        });
```

Comment: Working great! Thank you.